# A function without a return statement returns None?

Tags: python

This is a simple question:

In Python, if a function does not contain a `return` statement, does it automatically return `None`?

Comment: Yes, it will return None by default, you could verify by running a function that does not return anything and doing a `print(function())`

Answer (score 3):

Yes. From [the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions):

> In fact, even functions without a return statement do return a value, albeit a rather boring one. This value is called None (it’s a built-in name).